# Why would there be a problem to get the value of a semaphore and wait()

Tags: c, synchronization, semaphore, getvalue

Why would there be a problem to get the value of the semaphore and check it so that when the value of semaphore is > 0, we invoke wait()?
ie: Why would there be a problem for the following code?

```
if (getValue(&sem)>0){
    wait(&sem);
}
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that there is a problem?

Comment: It's a question in my courses's slides. But the professor didn't provide an answer for that. So I was just curious why this approach have a problem in it.

Comment: Generally speaking, you only wait on semaphores when their value is 0. Ergo, the `wait` wouldn't wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like the problem is here:

```
&sem>0
```

You do not pass a pointer to the semaphore (&sem) as argument, but an int (&sem > 0)

Did you try

```
getValue(&sem) > 0
```

?

Comment: Sorry, its just a typo when I write this question.